# Angular2 [style.width] binding high CPU usage

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I'm currently integrating a top-bar progress indicator for Angular (6.0).

I tried multiple npm packages, but all suffer from a high CPU usage as soon as I start the progress loader.

The Chrome Task Manager reports 50-80% CPU usage. Here is a minimal example from the following package: https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(loader.progress$|async) as progress">
    <div class="bar" [style.width.%]="progress">        
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingBarService implements OnDestroy {
  readonly progress$ = (new Subject<number>()).pipe(debounceTime(0)) as Subject<number>;

  private _pendingRequests = 0;
  private _value = 0;
  private _incTimeout: any;

  start(initialValue = 2) {
    ++this._pendingRequests;
    if (this._value === 0 || this._pendingRequests === 1) {
      this.set(this._pendingRequests === 1 && this._value > 0 ? this._value : initialValue);
    }
  }

  set(n) {
    if (n === 0 && this._pendingRequests > 0) {
      n = 2;
    }

    this._value = n;
    this.progress$.next(n);

    if (this._pendingRequests === 0) {
      return;
    }

    clearTimeout(this._incTimeout);
    if (this._value > 0 && this._value < 100) {
      this._incTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.increment(), 250);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the value is only updated every 250ms. But the CPU usage is consistently at ~60-70% (one core).

When I remove the binding `[style.width.%]` the CPU usage goes down to 5-10%.

Is it really that expensive updating the style width?

**Is there any better (faster) way updating the style's width?**

Because having such a high CPU usage when displaying the loader hurts the user experience when navigating pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I was importing the LoadingBarModule twice (in the main & component module). Removing the import from the components module fixed the issue.